# Function overloading by return const and not?

Tags: c++, overloading

I am reading HELib’s source code and come across the following class [definition](https://github.com/shaih/HElib/blob/15020f500cacfc41b610d81af4ea13d701893637/src/cloned_ptr.h#L142-L143):

```
#define CLONED_PTR_DECLARE(CLONED_PTR_TYPE,CLONED_PTR_INIT) \
 \
template <class X, class Cloner = CLONED_PTR_INIT<X> > class CLONED_PTR_TYPE \
{ \
......
    const X* get_ptr() const { return ptr; } \
    X* get_ptr() { return ptr; } \
......
}; \
\
```

But per my understanding, C++ doesn't have function overloading by return value. So what is the effect of these two `get_ptr()` functions?

Comment: The difference isn't just in the return type. Look again.

Comment: (I know the question doesn’t seem like a duplicate, but its answer answers your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the return type, it is the const keyword.  If you call the method on a const instance of the class, the const method will be called.